# How can I make an object emit light in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I'm using Blender for 4/5 weeks now, so, after learing the basics of modeling (i'm still not even decent), now i'm having some issues with ***Render Setup*** and ***Lights Setup***, and i hope someone can help me out! :)

**1. The Lightbulb**

I've modeled a really simple dog-character for an upcoming work. Having a lightbulb for head, i need it to emit some glow/light. I need a result which looks like the FIG. 2 (lights are made with PS), while the one i'm having now in Cycles is kinda flat FIG. 1
What's the best way to achieve it?

[image]

**2. Render Setup**

Even if my scene is almost...empty (1 model, 2 lights) seems like my Pc is working really hard (and slowly) to manage it, both in 3d view and rendering session.

*Windows 8 - 
AMD Phenom II X4core 965 Processor 
 - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti 
 -  8GB RAM*

Not a beast, but still decent enough for a project like this, i suppose.
(and i'm not forcing it, since render is still really noisy)
Since i'm supposed to build a scenario and rig/animate character, having a ***17/20 minute render time*** (for a frame) is really discouraging me :(
I've attached the Blender file, to see how i've set the render.

What's wrong with it? Am I doing something wrong with modeling or scene general setup? How can i have to speed up the render? Any suggestion will be very appreciated! :>

[Promise.blend](http://www.mediafire.com/download/a3my92bj5emz3k2/Promise.blend)

Comment: Welcome to the community. :D while it is crucial that you give enough detail so that we can answer your question, you should also try to make it as simple and short as possible. This question in particular has some unneeded information, which could be removed, since it is not essential in order to understand the it. If you would like to have lengthier discussions which are not necessarily on topic, you can join chat.

Comment: Making glass is rather tricky, so you may want to use glass nodes setup like one presented here - http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-realistic-materials-with-cycles/. Also, you shouldn't use lamp placed inside of the glass object to create this effect, rather than giving emission (like in the question linked) to the spiral which should emit light.